# Can ghost replenish hand in Reveal the Culprit phase

Tags: mysterium

In the Vision interpretation section of the rulebook, it says to draw `vision cards to make up his hand to 7 cards.`

In the Reveal the Culprit phase, it says `the ghost picks three vision cards from his hand`

It's not clear to me if the ghost is allowed to draw new cards to bring his or her hand up to 7 in the Reveal the Culprit phase every time he/she selects one of the three vision cards.

Can the ghost replenish his/her hand in the Reveal the Culprit phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the Reveal the Culprit section about drawing new cards in the middle of the vision therefore you don't. It is similar to the Vision Interpretation part of the game where if you give a psychic multiple cards as part of a single vision you don't draw in-between them, only after you are done with that particular vision and a ready to move to the next psychic's vision.